# Abstract algebra subgroup of a factor group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be an abelian group, and N is its normal subgroup, then we can consider the factor group G/N, if H is a subgroup of G/N, I wonder to know why H appears in the form T/N where T is a subgroup of G and T contains N ?

My attemption:
if g1N, g2N is in H, then (g1N)*(g2N)=(g1g2)N is also in H since H is a subgroup of G/N, then in my intuition I think H should be the form like H/N(hN | h in H), but I can't convince myself, is there another way to explain ?

Comment: Hello dREaM, for your writting on line four, should it be "morphism from T to G/N"?

Comment: Yes it should, sorry about that.

Comment: thanks for your help, now I'm more clear.

Comment: In the result, you say that T/N and H are isomorphic, but I still have a little question, can we conclude that T/N=H ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the surjective canonical projection $\varphi:G\rightarrow G/N$. Given a subgroup $H$ of $G/N$ we can consider $T=\varphi^{-1}({H})$. This is a subgroup of $G$ that clearly contains the kernel (since $H$ contains the identity, and $T$ is the complete preimage of $H$). So if we consider the restriction of $\varphi$ to the set $T$ we obtain a  morphism from $T$ to $G/N$ which has kernel $N$ and image $H$, the reason why the image is all of $H$ is that $\varphi$ is sujective when the domain is all of $G$.

by the first isomorphism theorem $\frac{T}{N}\cong H$ as desired.